# Snowflake Kafka Connnector Cluster Distributed Connector Services getting disconnected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

Error: This has disconnected the Server from Cluster and stopped the Distributed-Connector Services. Please help

```
[2021-12-08 14:07:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-12-08 14:17:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-12-08 14:24:23,198] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member connect-1-37b915a1-36f0-47df-81f0-f5b67985f278 in group connect-cluster has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-12-08 14:24:23,200] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group connect-cluster in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 18 (__consumer_offsets-13) (reason: removing member connect-1-37b915a1-36f0-47df-81f0-f5b67985f278 on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-12-08 14:24:25,680] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group connect-cluster generation 19 (__consumer_offsets-13) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-12-08 14:24:25,717] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group connect-cluster for generation 19 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-12-08 14:27:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-12-08 14:37:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-12-08 14:47:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2021-12-08 14:57:20,484] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Comment: With only this log snippet there isn't enough information to troubleshoot the issue. I would think it would be better to open a case with Snowflake in this situation.

Comment: Snowflake, it charges. Why do you think people come over here for posting their problems.

Comment: 1) There is no error here. Everything is a normal INFO message 2) They don't charge for specific community support - https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge